# Is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid unique?

Tags: windows, winapi

This [page](http://eigo.co.uk/labs/machine-universally-unique-identifier/) says the following:

> In the Windows registry is a key called MachineGUID that has a UUID
> which is created by Windows during installation and should in theory
> be unique to the machine. In practice this is not the case and I have
> often come across duplicates of this ID between machines.

I don't understand why it wouldn't be unique, I mean does Windows uses some weak algorithm to generate this GUID or something?

Comment: There's a reason why the various activation systems generate their own ID based on the hardware configuration of the machine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If a machine is restored from a backup or clone (such as in disaster-recovery, lab rollout, or fast VM deployment scenarios) then the `MachineGuid` value would be the same on multiple machines.

I note that the key value itself is read/write, so a post-setup or userland application could overwrite this too, even to a duplicate non-unique value.